# Скопировать часть строки

Tags: delphi

Есть база вот такого плана, как скопировать **часть строки до символа равно =** и вставить эту часть строки место того что находится после символа **двоеточия**.

```
Zakaz123=A.1234:12345
Zakaz333=B.1234:123
Zakaz3=S.1234:12
```

...........

**На выходе получить:**

```
Zakaz123=A.1234:Zakaz123
Zakaz333=B.1234:Zakaz333
Zakaz3=S.1234:Zakaz3
```

Вот мой код но ничего не получилось:

```
 while not Eof(f1) do
      begin
        // читаем строку
        ReadLn(f1, S);
        ReadLn(f1, s1);

        x3 := Pos(':', S);
        x2 := Pos('=', s2);

        if x3 > 0 then
        begin
          S := copy(S, 1, x3 - 1);
        end;

        if x2 > 0 then
        begin
          s2 := copy(S, x2 + 1, Length(s2) - x2);
        end;

        writeln(f1, s1 + ':' + s2);
      end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Все вопрос решила.

```
var
  i: Integer;
  sLeft, sRigth: String;
begin
  i := pos('=', s);
  if i > 0 then
    begin
      sLeft := copy(s, 1, i - 1);
      sRigth := copy(s, i + 1, Length(s) - i);
    end;
end;
```